# How do you prevent ONE radio button in a group from being selected, but allow others to deselect it?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

We have a form with a radio button group, where any one of the buttons may already be selected. We want to prevent a user from selecting one of the radio buttons, BUT we want to be able to 'deselect' that radio button by clicking on any other radio. Like so:

Step 1: (initial page load)

- R1: enabled and clickable
- R2: disabled, but CHECKED
- R3: enabled and clickable

Step 2: user clicks R1

- R1: enabled and CHECKED
- R2: disabled, NOT CHECKED
- R3: enabled and clickable

Will the 'disabled' attribute allow this to take place?

Comment: If you don't want a particular radio button to be selected, or even selectable, why is it on the page to start with? I know that a non-available option typically irritates me when I encounter them.

Comment: I agree with ricebowl. If there's an option that is not selectable, then I'd want an obvious reason as to why it isn't selectable. A good example of that would be the "State" option in a form. Someone from France, for example, wouldn't need to fill out the "State" option. However, it would still be there for the users who are in the US.

Comment: Hi guys. Thanks for your opinion. I left out the majority of the use case because I didn't want to explain the intricacies of the system. As I'm sure you're aware, applications can be quite complicated, which is why I left that piece out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it will.

Here's a quick example: http://jsbin.com/onuci

Of course, I'm not using any JavaScript for it, but I just wanted to show that a disabled radio button (R2 in the example) can be checked, but then when the user clicks either of the other two buttons, it becomes unchecked and cannot be checked again.

Comment: Heh...I should've just tested it myself :-). But hey, you got a couple extra rep points for an easy-peasy (or is it peasie?). Thanks Jeff!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using Check boxes for this. What happens if I accidentally activated "R1" and then wanted to deactivate it?

Comment: Yup, that's part of the use case that I did not explain...Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

jQuery can achieve this quite easily: http://jquery.com/

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load("jquery", "1.3.2");

        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("r1").click(function () { 
                $("r2").removeAttr("checked");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="form_action.php" method="get">
  <input id="r1" type="radio" name="dog" value="Gus" /> Gus<br />
  <input id="r2" type="radio" name="dog" value="Bruce" checked="checked" disabled="disabled" /> Bruce<br />
  <input id="r3" type="radio" name="dog" value="Champ" /> Champ<br />
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Bah, over engineering on my part.